# AIX agent failing after Bamboo upgrade 5.5->5.7

Tags: java, jna, aix, bamboo

We always have hard time with Bamboo upgrades because AIX agents are not officially supported. No exception this one, from 5.5.1 to 5.7.2 (sad) It is trying to receive/start a job and apparently is failing to read some serialized XML. Last time moving to 5.5.1 we had to use previous version of JNA (3.4.0) instead one packaged with Bamboo (4.1.0). It did not happen this time so we use the latest one that comes with Bamboo 5.7. Agent comes on-line but fails to execute even simple commands (sad) Any ideas would be appreciated!

The java version on AIX currently is:

```
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6470sr6fp1-20140108_01(SR6 FP1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 AIX ppc64-64 Compressed References 20140106_181350 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR6_20140106_1601_B181350
JIT  - r11.b05_20131003_47443.02
GC   - R26_Java726_SR6_20140106_1601_B181350_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20140106_181350)
JCL - 20140103_01 based on Oracle 7u51-b11
```

And here is part of the log showing error when agent is trying to execute the very first job:

```
2015-01-08 12:11:38,417 INFO [Thread-5] [AgentHeartBeatJobScheduler] Scheduled AgentHeartBeatJobScheduler to run every 60s. Next run at Thu Jan 08 12:11:38 PST 2015
2015-01-08 12:11:38,455 INFO [Thread-5] [RemoteAgent] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
2015-01-08 12:11:38,455 INFO [Thread-5] [RemoteAgent] *                                                                                                                                                *
2015-01-08 12:11:38,455 INFO [Thread-5] [RemoteAgent] * Bamboo agent 'ibmaix71vm2.woods.ad' ready to receive builds.
2015-01-08 12:11:38,455 INFO [Thread-5] [RemoteAgent] * Remote Agent Home: /bamboo/bamboo-agent-home
2015-01-08 12:11:38,456 INFO [Thread-5] [RemoteAgent] * Broker URL: failover:(tcp://192.168.223.200:54663?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=300000)?initialReconnectDelay=15000&maxReconnectAttempts=10
2015-01-08 12:11:38,456 INFO [Thread-5] [RemoteAgent] *                                                                                                                                                *
2015-01-08 12:11:38,456 INFO [Thread-5] [RemoteAgent] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
2015-01-08 12:11:38,511 INFO [scheduler_Worker-1] [AgentHeartBeatJob] executableBuildAgent still unavailable. Heartbeat skipped.
2015-01-08 12:16:38,425 INFO [0-BAM::ibmaix71vm2.woods.ad::Agent:pool-3-thread-1] [BuildAgentControllerImpl] Agent 747175938 checking build queue for executables...
2015-01-08 12:16:38,825 ERROR [0-BAM::ibmaix71vm2.woods.ad::Agent:pool-3-thread-1] [BuildAgentControllerImpl] Unknown exception occurred on 'ibmaix71vm2.woods.ad'. Agent will attempt to recover its normal operation...
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Null : java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Null
---- Debugging information ----
message             : java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Null
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Null
class               : com.atlassian.util.concurrent.ResettableLazyReference$InternalReference
required-type       : com.atlassian.util.concurrent.ResettableLazyReference$InternalReference
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /result/value/parentBuildContext/variableContext/effectiveStateRef/referrent/queue
line number         : 234
class[1]            : com.atlassian.bamboo.variable.VariableContextImpl$1
class[2]            : com.atlassian.bamboo.variable.VariableContextImpl
class[3]            : com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.BuildContextImpl
converter-type[1]   : com.atlassian.bamboo.serialization.xstream.BuildContextXStreamConverter
class[4]            : org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationResult
version             : not available
-------------------------------
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:474)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:406)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:257)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
```

Comment: The latest source from Git has issues with unloading on AIX (some interaction with the JVM I'm guessing, it crashes calling back to the VM during JNI_OnUnload).  However, other VMs may have more success (IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc-32).

Comment: @technomage - thanks for the insight. Looks like going for a different JVM is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Someone at Atlassian suggested to try [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) and it solved our problem. We didn't have time to try different JVM builds as per @technomage, but found this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/aix/service.html) for downloads.